# Regex to prevent double byte characters. Only allow ascii in a range

Tags: regex

I have a regex for password control. It will only allow alphanumeric characters and some symbols.

```
 "^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[#?!$%^&-*@0-9])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,128})$$"
```

Now I want to prevent any double byte characters being used in the password.

I've tried having a list that only allows ascii but that didnt work `^[ -&#2303;]+$`

Tried having a list in a range `?=.*[0x21-0x7e]`

Would it be possible to flip the logic on my first regex so that if it was a character NOT included in the list it wouldn't allow entry?

I have discovered if I use only double byte it doesn't allow entry but it will if I include a single double byte. I don't want any.

This is in a finnicky scripting language nsis so cant rely on many functions just pattern matching .

Comment: You need to use the restricting character class in place of the last dot (`.{8,128}`), not inside the Lookaheads.

Comment: Bug alert! `[#?!$%^&-*@0-9]` should be `[#?!$%^&*@0-9-]`: you don’t want the range `&` to `*`, either escape the dash or put it first or last.

Comment: The class range can be written as a visually clearer `[a-zA-Z0-9!-/:-@\[\]-\`{-~]{8,128}` or it can be a range using a Byte construct `[\x21-\x7e]{8,128}`. Whats important is that the lookaheads contain a required character(s) as you have it.

Answer (score 1):

The dot allows any character, so replace it with an ASCII range `[!-z]`:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[#?!$%^&*@0-9-])(?=.*[A-Z])[!-z]{8,128}$
```

Note that the backtick is included in this range, and tilda `~` is excluded.
To exclude backtick use `[!-_a-z]`.
To include tilda, use `[!-~]`.
To do both, use `[!-_a-~]`.

Bug in symbol character class fixed: `[#?!$%^&-*@0-9]` should be `[#?!$%^&*@0-9-]`: you don’t want the range `&` to `*`, either escape the dash or put it first or last.

Unnecessary group removed.

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately, still accepting double byte. Might be an issue with the scripting language

Comment: @RogerDodger can you post a sample of the problem input?